# How to view CLR ETW events

Tags: .net, clr, etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I was wondering if there is a tool that can be used to view CLR [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) events in particular, i.e. display "nice" graphs rather than appearing in a generic event section in [WPA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448170.aspx) using generic graphs.

Opening a .etl trace file (e.g. made with [perfmonitor.exe](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PerfMonitor&referringTitle=Home) or WPR) trace in WPA gives me nothing but GUIDs and event IDs (for CLR events) to dig through, so I was wondering if there's a way to resolve these to more useful names in WPA or if there is another tool that can display such event traces. perfmonitor.exe is only partly useful because it focuses on JIT, GC and CPU only and (afaik) ignores other events.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022660/5784920

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Tool [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567). It doesn't show graphs, but it very good to show CLR data.

The author posted [some tutorial videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/).