# WPA does not see ETW event data, tracerpt does

Tags: sql-server, wmi, etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I am capturing ADO.Net diagnostics ETW, as described in [Data Access Tracing in SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421(SQL.100).aspx). The setup works, an ETL file is produced and I can see the ADO.Net trace if I use, say, [tracerpt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732700(v=ws.11).aspx):

```
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603462277,        450,       2400,        2, "enter_01 <prov.DbConnectionHelper.CreateDbCommand|API> 1# "
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603469806,        450,       2400,        2, "<sc.SqlCommand.set_Connection|API> 1#, 1# "
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603469816,        450,       2400,        2, "leave_01 "
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603471294,        450,       2400,        2, "<sc.SqlCommand.set_CommandText|API> 1#, '"
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603474160,        450,       2400,        2, "select cast(serverproperty('EngineEdition') as int)"
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603474174,        450,       2400,        2, "' "
 System.Data,      TextA,            0,          0,          0,          0,         17,          0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007D0, 0x00003A64,                    1,             ,                     ,   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},                                         ,   131485096603523068,        450,       2400,        2, "<sc.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader|INFO> 1#, Command executed as SQLBATCH. "
```

But if I load the same ETL into [WPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer) I see nothing useful about the events captured. All events from this provider display `Event Name` `<Unknown>`, `Event Type` `Classic` and no info about the actual ADO.Net event info (ie. the rightmost column in the tracerpt CSV output):

```
Line #, Provider Name, Task Name, Type (Opcode/Type ), Opcode Name, Id, Process, Annotation, Event Name, Event Type, Message, Cpu, ThreadId, Message, UserDataLength, Time (s)
1, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 3, 14056, , 0, 22.877068496
2, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 0, 14056, , 0, 22.877265256
3, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 0, 14056, , 0, 22.877275482
4, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 0, 14056, , 0, 22.877276892
5, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 0, 14056, , 0, 22.877299460
6, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 0, 14056, , 0, 22.877301223
7, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 1, 13276, , 0, 23.061972110
8, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 1, 13276, , 0, 23.061975636
9, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 1, 13276, , 0, 23.062004550
10, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 1, 13276, , 0, 23.063588859
11, 914abde3-171e-c600-3348-c514171de148, <Unknown>, 17, , 0, Unknown, <Not Annotated>, <Unknown>, Classic, , 1, 13276, , 0, 23.063617421
```

Since all other data I capture I can analyze in WPA, I wonder what is different about the ADO.Net diag provider that the events are so opaque to WPA?

Comment: I have the same difficulties. FYI I use Microsoft Message Analyzer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649776.aspx) and it works (with the exact same .etl) with some tweaking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Performance Analyzer reads the manifest data from registry to decode the events. If WPA fails to get the data it shows only the GUID for provider and `<Unknown>` for Taskname and Eventname. Those [Managed Object Format (MOF) files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/weg/instrumenting-your-code-with-etw#overview) which ares by ADO tracing are not supported by WPA (classic, legacy provider), but it looks like `tracerpt.exe` does support it.

For raw analysis of ETL files to only look for Events, I suggest [Perfview](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview).

It has its own parsers to get decode Events:

[image]

```
<Event MSec= "26176,0393" PID="11304" PName="foo" TID="8336" EventName="AdoNetDiag/TextW"
  TimeStamp="09.02.17 16:47:39.338496" ID="Illegal" Version="0" Keywords="0x00000000" TimeStampQPC="1.241.241.278.025"
  Level="Always" ProviderName="Bid2Etw_ADONETDIAG_ETW" ProviderGuid="7acdcac8-8947-f88a-e51a-24018f5129ef" ClassicProvider="True"
  Opcode="18" TaskGuid="7acdcac9-8947-f88a-e51a-24018f5129ef" Channel="0" PointerSize="4"
  CPU="1" EventIndex="1328680" TemplateType="DynamicTraceEventData">
  <PrettyPrint>
    <Event MSec= "26176,0393" PID="11304" PName="foo" TID="8336" EventName="AdoNetDiag/TextW" ProviderName="Bid2Etw_ADONETDIAG_ETW" ModID="0" msgStr="01:CONNECTED [526D0000]C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll  &quot;System.Data.SNI.1&quot; {C9996FA5-C06F-F20C-8A20-69B3BA392315}
    "/>
  </PrettyPrint>
```

So use WPA for performance analysis of CPU, disk, file io and Perfview for the events.