# C# Data Access Tracing for ADO.Net - Need to do profiler to check what are all connection is being shared across multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ado.net, trace

I have tried to enable Data Access Tracing using ETW as explained in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455562/Diagnosing-ADO-NET-with-ETW-Traces).

To verify that it traces the event, I have created a simple console application instead of the MVC application as it is there in the article. Code as follows, it is intended to throw so i can verify the trace works.

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=local;Trusted_Connection = True; Initial Catalog = Data; Timeout = 2; Max Pool Size = 4";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DATA", conn))
   {
      conn.Open();
      var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      using (var data = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PEOPLE", conn))
      {
           var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
      }
   }
}
```

I am using .Net Framework v4.0.30319. 
Ideally i want to trace the connection objects which are being shared between threads. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [register the MOFs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx), use [Perview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022660/1466046)->Collect->provider-browser and add everything from ADO.net and SQL, click on start and run your code. after code was running, go to perfview and stop logging and look for the ADO/SQL events

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Try registering the other .dll/mof pairs instead of the one recommended by your guide.

The steps to manually register the DLL (modified from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971550.aspx) MS guide)

- Add the following registry key

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BidInterface\Loader
- Create a new **string value** (note the ':' in the key) and **Modify...** it

  > **Value Name** = ":Path"
  >
  > **Value Data** = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AdoNetDiag.dll"
- Register ETW Providers in your WMI repository with mofcomp.exe (installed with windows)

  > **mofcomp.exe** C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\adonetdiag.mof

To test:

```
logman start test -p "System.Data.1" -o test.etl -ets // Start a trace
// Do things with ADO.NET (run your sample)
logman stop test -ets // Stop a started trace
tracerpt.exe test.etl -of CSV -o dump.csv // make it human readable
```

If things worked, you should now have a summary.txt and dump.csv file in the same directory filled with tracing information. Good luck.

---

Which `ADONETDIAG.dll` did you register with those steps? I followed [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971550.aspx) (they appear to be the ones Microsoft published that everyone else uses for their guides) and found them to work with one gotcha.

The one gotcha I discovered is that there can be multiple copies of `ADONETDIAG.dll` installed on your machine - and **the DLL you register matters!** For example, my machine has one installed in the following locations

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\AdoNetDiag.dll
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AdoNetDiag.dll
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\AdoNetDiag.dll
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\AdoNetDiag.dll

All of the steps I've found direct you to register `\Framework\v2.0.50727\AdoNetDiag.dll`. When I tried this I was not getting any logs (my .etl files capture 1 event, the trace start, and never grow beyond 8KB).

Trial and error led to discovering `\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AdoNetDiag.dll` working for me.